# Constructing a 10^6 by 10^6 matrix crashes python

Tags: python, matrix, memory-management, out-of-memory

I need to compute the kernel of a matrix, which has 10^6 by 10^6 entries. The way I obtain this matrix is by generating its entries according to some algorithm, one column at a time.

My problem is that when I run my code, it crashes due to a lack of memory. Roughly speaking, it seems like my matrix requires 32 bits * 10^6 * 10^6 of space, which is about 3.5 terabytes. I understand that my PC isn't built for that, however, trying to write the matrix into a CSV file is incredibly slow. Is there a better way of doing this? Right now I am working in Python but I am open to alternative suggestions.

Comment: Why do you need to keep the whole matrix if it is generated by an algorithm?

Comment: I need to compute its kernel, which is not generated by the algorithm

Comment: You don't need the whole matrix to compute the kernel, you only need one element at a time.

Comment: Do you have any specific algorithm in mind? I do not see how you can compute a matrix's echelon form without the whole matrix. Maybe you have something different in mind.

Comment: Gaussian elimination is `O(n^3)` so even if you get the memory problem solved you might run into a time problem. Perhaps you could ask on [mathematics.se] about algorithms for finding the kernel of a large matrix.